# Why does carrier density change linearly over the depletion region?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The [Feynman Lectures on Physics vol III, section 14-4](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_14.html) shows the following for a pn junction (a), with (b) representing potential and (c) representing carrier density:

[image: Potential in a semiconductor]

Why does the carrier density vary as shown in (c)? Images of the depletion region show a negative charge associated with the p-type side of the region, and a positive charge associated with the n-type side, so surely there should be a greater electron density in the p-type side of the region and a greater hole density in the n-type side?

Comment: The actual shape depends on the doping profiles in the $n$ and $p$ regions. What you have shown is a simple didactic representation - don't read too much into it.

Answer (score 0):

The carrier densities far away from the depletion region will be the equilibrium densities of *n* and *p* type carriers respectively. However **in** the depletion region because the *p*-type and *n*-type materials are in contact the majority carriers (let's take the case of *p* type) will be attracted and hence diffuse to the *n* type material. This process will stop when the positive charge builds up in the *n* type material (as the electrons would be diffusing (**lost**) to the *p* type) and vice versa for the other side. 
 The possibility of electron density on the *p*-type cannot extend beyond a certain limit and certainly not be more than the majority carriers under transient or equilibrium conditions. The majority carriers will still be donor sites i.e,holes.